# invoke ImportTsv from oozie to load to hbase

Tags: import, hbase, oozie

what is the best way to invoke importtsv from oozie. This is what I want to run via oozie :

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=',' -Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf:name" nameTab hdfs://xyz.com:8020/user/me/name.csv
```

Do I have to put this in script, if so how to invoke hbase, and what are the libraries to be added . newbie please help .

Answer (score 0):

Oozie does not have `hbase` action to use directly. I guess, you can use the `shell` action, put this command in to a shell script.

Important thing here is, `shell` action executed using a launcher mapper job, which can be scheduled/launched on any machine on the cluster. So hbase client must be installed on all the nodes in the cluster.

You can copy the Hbase related jars in to the `lib` directory of the workflow, in the HDFS.

You can add the following jars along: (check/choose the version as per your need).

```
hbase-xxx.jar
hbase-procedure-1.1.2.jar
hbase-server-1.1.2.jar
hbase-common-1.1.2.jar
hbase-client-1.1.2.jar
hbase-protocol-1.1.2.jar
```